# Ph.D. candidate publishing preprint to link papers

Tags: publications, arxiv

I have two papers that I'm looking to try and publish soon. I would like to cite my own paper as the work is fairly closely linked. Is it worth publishing one as a preprint on something like Arxiv so I can cite? I've read that it is more beneficial to publish preprints if you are already an established researcher whereas these would be my first two publications (if accpeted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can post the preprints version of the paper before submitting if the journals do not have a policy which require you not to publish the preprint on repositories like arxiv, vixra, etc. See for example [International Journal of Modern Physics D](http://www.worldscientific.com/page/authors/peer-review-policy), where they have a policy of embargo which is explained. From [this link](http://www.worldscientific.com/page/authors/author-rights) you can see the author rights "After an embargo of 12 months, you may post the accepted author manuscript on your personal website, your institutional or subject repositories of your own choice or as stipulated by the Funding Agency. 
"

To be clear, when you publish on arxiv, you give the an irrevocable license to distribute the article to arxiv, which means that you cannot withdraw the paper from arxiv unless there is a crucial mistake on it (see [here](https://arxiv.org/help/withdraw) ).

[Here](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/search.php?issn=0031-9007) you can see the policies for many journals, for example
"Author's Pre-print:    green tick  author can archive pre-print (ie pre-refereeing)
Author's Post-print:    green tick  author can archive post-print (ie final draft post-refereeing)
Publisher's Version/PDF:    green tick  author can archive publisher's version/PDF
General Conditions: 
On author's personal website, employer's website or institutional repository
Publisher's version/PDF may be used
Publisher's version/PDF may be used on author's personal website or employer's website only
Link to publisher version required
Publisher copyright and source must be acknowledged with citation"

Finally, you need to check with the policy of the journal where you have submitted the 2 papers, and if you cannot publish on arxiv, you can cite with something like "_authors, paper name, submitted".

In the present, the world will go to open access, and we as authors have to encourage these movements and to publish the preprints online on free repositories.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. So the journals I'm looking at do accept arxiv; would you recommend a Ph.D. candidate to look to preprint? Personally, I'm all for open access - I think apart from the ethics of sharing knowledge it's also a great way to get your work out there.

Comment: @MikeMiller what do you mean by "would you recommend a Ph.D. candidate to look to preprint"?

Comment: As in would you recommend doing this or just submitting to a journal.

Comment: IMHO you can submit to arxiv and to the journals. Nowadays, people look for papers more on arxiv since it is more convenient. Good luck with your work!

Comment: *when you publish on arxiv, you give the copyright to the paper to arxiv for good* -- No, you don't. You give Arxiv an irrevocable license to distribute the article, but you keep the copyright. See here: https://arxiv.org/help/license

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Mike Since you do math, you should always put your papers on arXiv when they are ready (i.e just before submitting to a journal) and you can then update with whatever changes are suggested by referees. Journals which do not allow this can safely be ignored in our field (there are always equivalent journals which do allow it).

Comment: This is still not quite accurate as to arXiv's withdrawal policy.  An author can *withdraw* a paper from arXiv at any time and for any reason (it doesn't have to be a "serious error", though that would be the most usual reason).  But that doesn't *remove* the paper from the site; previous versions remain available forever, it just takes one extra click.  There is no way at all to completely remove a paper, even if it does contain a serious error.  (Maybe arXiv would remove a paper if it violated copyright or something, but that would be up to them, not up to the author.)